# Declare a large Array in javascript indicating its size, without assigning values

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

In a web page that uses javascript, I need to maximize the speed with which it is filled
an array (myArray).

The way I will use to do this is summarized with the following example, which fills an array of integers
called Array1:

1) The usual way to enter elements in Array1 is:

```
var Array1 = [5,7];
Array1.push (10);
```

2) But if I know a priori the size I will need for the Array, it is much faster to do so:

```
var Array1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; // Allocated array of length 5.
var A1Length = 0;
// to do a 'push', do
Array1 [A1Length ++] = 10;
```

However, the Array that I am using on my website (myArray) does not contain integers, but objects
each of which is an array of two elements.
It is not a two-dimensional Array, but an array that contains Array objects.
I will use it as a map where "A" is the key, and "B" is the value that I am looking for.

Currently, I fill it like this and it works correctly:

```
var myArray = [];
var newElement = {"A": 10, "B": 'Name 1'}
myArray.push (newElement);
```

To increase the speed with which myArray is filled, following the example discussed for Array1,
I need to declare it with the size that will have (1000 Array objects of two dimensions).

I have tried to declare it like this:

```
var myArray = Array.from (Array (1000), () => new Array (2));
var myArrayUsed = 0;
```

And then insert new elements in it:

```
var newElement = {"A": 10, "B": 'Name 1'}
myArray [myArrayUsed ++] = newElement;
```

The problem is that this code does not work and I think it is because myArray declaration statement
is not correct.

Comment: I would tend to doubt that array initialization is really a significant performance problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
var myArray = Array(1000);
var myArrayUsed = 0;

var newElement = {"A": 10, "B": 'Name 1'};
myArray [myArrayUsed ++] = newElement;
```

And you said

> I will use it as a map where "A" is the key, and "B" is the value that I am looking for.

Why do you write {"A": 10, "B": "Name 1"} but not a simple object like {"10": "Name 1"}? "A" and "B" are values of variables?